# Wow6432node redirection for 32 bit exe

Tags: mfc, registry, 32bit-64bit

I have one 64 bit applicatoin , which uses some 32 bit graphic exes.
While i am doing createprocess for that 32 bit exes , its looks for registry path in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\**Wow6432Node**\MyApp" .
But as my application is 64 bit , all registry entries is in 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp".
As result creatprocess fot 32 bit graphic exe fails.
My Question is that "Is there any way so those 32 bit exe also looks for there registry path in default 64 bit registry path instead of wow6432node ?"

P.S. I cant convert those 32 bit exe into 64 bit as I don't have the source code for those 32bit graphic exes .

Please provide me any help to resolve this issue.

Regards..

Comment: Hello , i think there is no way to do this , only one way is to convert the 32 bit exe into 64 bit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way so those 32 bit exe also looks for their registry path in default 64 bit registry path instead of wow6432node ?"

The only possible solution is to port 32 bit exe into 64 bit